# Problem with compiling: ! LaTeX Error: File `./fig/Q_a_x' not found

Tags: graphics, compiling, eps

The folder `fig` is in the same directory as the `.tex` file, and the figure `Q_a_x.eps` is inside the folder `fig`. This problem happens when I compile it using `pdflatex` in linux. Is there any way to solve this problem, but keeping compiling using `pdflatex`, instead of `latex`? Thanks in advance!

The positions of the files is as shown here:
[image]

And the figure is included in the tex file as:

```
    \begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=3.4in]{./fig/Q_a_x.eps}
\caption{$Q^{GW}(a_*,x)$ as a function of x for different $a_*$'s.}
\label{figQ-a-x}
\end{figure}
```

Here is the output from pdflatex compiling:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./kerr.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex4/revtex4.cls
Document Class: revtex4 2001/08/02 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/
for documentation)
ltxutil: portions licensed from W. E. Baxter (web@superscript.com)
ltxgrid: portions licensed from W. E. Baxter (web@superscript.com)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex4/revsymb.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex4/aps.rtx)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex4/10pt.rtx)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/etc/texmf/tex/latex/config/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/epsfig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/etc/texmf/tex/latex/config/color.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/etc/texmf/tex/latex/config/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfig/subfig.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty)

Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
(caption)                usage of the caption package is not recommended.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)) (./kerr.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)

Package hyperref Warning: Height of page (\paperheight) is invalid (0.0pt),
(hyperref)                using 11in.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./kerr.out) (./kerr.out)

Package caption Warning: \caption will not be redefined since it's already
(caption)                redefined by a document class or package which is
(caption)                unknown to the caption package.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Reference `conclusions' on page 1 undefined on input line 74.

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Overfull \hbox (5.00699pt too wide) in alignment at lines 86--89
 [][][] []

LaTeX Warning: Reference `appendix:spin' on page 2 undefined on input
line 93.


Underfull \hbox (badness 4013) in paragraph at lines 93--95
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 The above an-gu-lar equa-tion is the well-known

LaTeX Warning: Reference `appendix:spin' on page 2 undefined on input
line 112.



Package hyperref Warning: Ignoring empty anchor on input line 114.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `appendix:setup' on page 2 undefined on input
line 120
.

[2]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 126--128
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 We first de-fine a di-men-sion-less quan-tity

Underfull \hbox (badness 1142) in paragraph at lines 126--128
\OML/cmm/m/it/10 Q[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 (\OML/cmm/m/it/10 a[];
M!\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )$
, which rep-re-sents the ex-pected emis-

Overfull \hbox (8.801pt too wide) in alignment at lines 128--132
 [][][] []

! LaTeX Error: File `./fig/Q_a_x' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

The preamble of my tex file is here:

```
\documentclass[prd, amsfonts, twocolumn, nofootinbib, showpacs]{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx, epsfig}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\lower0.6ex\hbox{$\sim$}}}
\newcommand{\lapp}{\mathrel{\raise.3ex\hbox{$<$}\mkern-14mu \lower0.6ex\hbox{$\sim$}}}
\def\bbox{{\,\lower0.9pt\vbox{\hrule \hbox{\vrule height 0.2 cm
\hskip 0.2 cm \vrule  height 0.2 cm}\hrule}\,}}

\makeatletter
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% EDITING MARKUP %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. f the LaTeX can't find the file, than (i) file not exist or (ii) path to the file is ill defined. So, you should provide minimal complete document (named Minimal Working Example) which will exhibits your problem and show path to your figure.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to load the eps file? With `\includegraphics{./fig/Q_a_x}`, with `\includegraphics{./fig/Q_a_x.eps}`, or by some other method? Please advise.

Comment: @Zarko and Mico: Thank you for your reply. I've added the path and the includegraphics part of the my code.

Comment: It looks like you're using TeXLive2013 -- any chance you can update your system to TeXLive2015?

Comment: Please also post the entire preamble of your document. Judging by the contents of the log file, some packages are possibly being loaded in a suboptimal way.

Answer (score 3):

`pdflatex` accepts (almost) every image file except `.eps`. Try converting it to `.pdf`, `.png` or anything convenient.

Otherwise, you could use `epstopdf` package, which does the work for you automatically. In that case, you should add `\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./fig/}`, to tell it where to put the produced `.pdf` file.

Comment: With recent TeX distributions, the `epstopdf` package is loaded automatically if a non-pdf grapics file is supposed to be loaded.

Comment: Aah, additional information provided by the OP shows that TeXlive2013 is in use. For that version, it may indeed still be necessary to load the `epstopdf` package explicitly.

Comment: @Mico, the first line of the output showed TeX Live 2013, which did not load it automatically as far as I remember. Either way, I wasn't aware of the automatic loading (I don't use it myself, I prefer distinct image files). Thank you for the update.

Comment: I just compiled it on another computer using pdflatex. The version is also TeXlive2013 on this one. But now the problem becomes "! Package pdftex.def Error: File `./fig/figure_file_name-eps-converted-to.
pdf' not found." This is a more common and understandable problem caused by failure during conversion from eps to pdf. I get totally confused now by the strange "!Latex: File 'figure' not found" error on the first computer...

Comment: Try moving file `Q_a_x.eps` in the same directory with your `.tex` file and see if the `.pdf` file is produced. Also change your command to `\includegraphics{Q_a_x}`.